# IF Function not knowing the less than "0" values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a simple calculation with excel as if the divided number is less than "0", I would like to show the value as "1" and if greater than "0", just show the actual answer.
This is my excel formula

> =IF((A2/3)<=0,1,A2/3)

, But the formula never show "True" value as "1" and only showing the "False" value as "A2/3"
I don't know what is missing to calculate this.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  You might want to also include sample data which helps to explain the problem you are having here.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, Let say I have a list of values in A column as 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
In B1 column, I started writing my formula as " =IF(A1/3>0,A1/3,"Less Than Zero Problem")".
In theory, If we divided 1 by 3, the value should return as less than Zero (answer is 0.33333). Right!
If the formula is work properly, it should return "Less Than Zero Problem" but now i only got 0.3333

Comment: Based on the answer you have accepted, it seems that you have wrongly worded your question. FWIW, 0.3333 is not less than 0. What you probably want is not less than 1...like `=IF((A2/3)<=1,1,A2/3)`.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij
got the point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `=MAX(A2/3,1)`. It won't show a value lower than 1.

Comment: Thank you, I should use MAX instead of IF function.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem, either.

But I think you could rewrite your formula as

```
=If(A2<=0,1,A2/3)
```

Comment: `I cannot reproduce your problem, either.` ... then please vote to close as a typo question, don't answer :-)